# How to read from file and store in a multidimentional array in PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to read from a file and store in a multidimensional array. My final array should look like that:

```
$products = [
     "tshirt" => [
          "color" => "red",
          "designer" => "hisName",
          "year" => "2000"
          ]
     "pants" => [
          "color" => "black,
          "designer" => "hisName",
          "year" => "2003"
          ]
    ]
```

I am confused since I am not getting how to specify where to store the data in the array.

here's my code:

```
<?php
$lignes = file('./file.txt');
$index = 0;
$indexId = 0;

foreach($lignes as $ligne){
    $ligne = trim($ligne);
    if($index == 0){
        $id = $ligne;
        $livres[$indexId] = $id;
        $indexId++;
        $index++;
    }elseif($ligne != "+ + +"){
        $livres[$id][] = $ligne;
    }else{
        $index = 0;
    }
}
?>
```

And here's a preview of the content of file.txt:

```
type
color
designer
year
+ + +
type
color
designer
year
```

each entry is separated by + + +

Comment: What is the contents of ``file.txt``?

Comment: @kmoser I edited the question and added a preview of the file.txt

Comment: This still doesn't make sense. If the textfile contains only words like "type", "color", "designer" and "year", where do the actual values come from, e.g. "t-shirt", "red", "hisName", "2000"?

Comment: @kmoser you can replace designer year type and color with any other string. it doesn't matter that's why I said it's a preview:
I hope this is clear:
tshirt
red
hisName
2000
+ + +
pants
black
hisName
2003

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the product, color, designer and year are always in that order:

```
<?php

for( $i=0; $i < sizeof( $lignes ); $i++ ){
    $product = $lignes[ $i++ ];
    $products[ $product ][ 'color' ] = $lignes[ $i++ ];
    $products[ $product ][ 'designer' ] = $lignes[ $i++ ];
    $products[ $product ][ 'year' ] = $lignes[ $i++ ];
}
```

Comment: is it a god practice to increment the index inside the for loop?

Comment: It is neither good nor bad; this is the algorithm I'm using, based on the assumptions in your original code. Specifically that there will always be a product, followed by color, designer, and year, in that order.

Answer (score 1):

Your text file needs more information unless all the information is in a specific order... Somehow a key has to be tied to a value in the text file so I'm assuming every 1st element is the category and the elements after that are specific keys like color, etc. I mimicked your text file into an array .. this would happen with your file() statement... you can also use a switch() command but I tried to follow your code as closely as possibly.

```
<?php

$lignes = array('tshirt','red','hisName','2000','+ + +','pants','black','hisName','2003');
$index = 0;
$category = "";
$type = "";

foreach($lignes as $ligne){
    $ligne = trim($ligne);
    if($index == 0) { $category = $ligne; } 
    elseif ($index == 1) { $type = "color"; } 
    elseif ($index == 2) { $type = "designer"; } 
    elseif ($index == 3) { $type = "year"; } 
    elseif ($ligne == "+ + +") {
        $index = -1;
        $category = "";
        $type = "";
        }
    $index++;

    if ($category && $type) {
        $livres[$category][$type] = $ligne;
        }
    }

print "<pre>";
print_r($livres);
print "</pre>";
?>
```

My result was:

```
Array
(
    [tshirt] => Array
        (
            [color] => red
            [designer] => hisName
            [year] => 2000
        )

    [pants] => Array
        (
            [color] => black
            [designer] => hisName
            [year] => 2003
        )

)
```